# Proving an implicit function is convex

Tags: calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I need to do the following: show that the equation $x \cdot $ cos $(x \cdot y)=0$ has a unique solution in the neighborhood of the point $(1,\frac{\pi}{2})$ (we will denote it $y(x)$), and that $y(x)$ is a convex function in that neighborhood.

For the first part, I used the implicit function theorem to show that there is a unique $y(x)$. Now I want to show it is convex; I have found that the derivative is: $$y'(x)=\frac{\cos\bigl(x \cdot y(x)\bigr)-x \cdot y(x) \cdot \sin\bigl(x \cdot y(x)\bigr)}{x^2 \cdot \sin\bigl(x \cdot y(x)\bigr )}$$
Now  in order to show it is convex, I thought about showing that $y'(x)$ is increasing in that neighborhood, but I don't know how to do it since I don't know much about that neighborhood nor about $y(x)$. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't tell whether $(1, \pi/2)$ is supposed to be an interval on the real line or a point in the plane.

Comment: A point in the plain. I will edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Edited, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Can you tell us numerically what $y'(x)$ is at the point $(x, y) = (1, \frac{\pi}{2})$? What does that say about $y'$ in a neighborhood of that point (given that the formula for $y'$ is very nice)?

Comment: The value of $y'(x)$ at that point is $-\pi$ / 2, but I'm not sure how that helps me. I only know that $y'(x)$ is negative in that neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \cdot \cos (x \cdot y) = 0$. Then $x = 0$ or $\cos(x \cdot y) = 0$. In the latter case, this is equivalent to $x \cdot y = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 k \pi$ for some $k$. Note that the vertical line $x = 0$ can never contribute to any of these continuous function curves, so literally, your solution must be of the form,

$$y = \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 k \pi}{x}.$$

Given that it passes through the point $(1, \pi/2)$, we're looking at $k = 0$. So, the function in question is,

$$y = \frac{\pi}{2x}$$

which is convex for $x > 0$.